# Incorrect URL displayed upon using driver.getCurrentUrl() in Webdriver, Selenium

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a register form, which is filled by Selenium Webdriver, it submits and goes to the post registration page. Upon checking the URL with driver.getCurrentUrl() the previous page url is returned.

```
driver.get(baseUrl + "home") // url /home
driver.findElement(By.id(<<button>>).click();   // url -> /register

driver.findElement(By.id(<<textfield>>).sendKeys("the entire form is filled"); // url /register

driver.findElement(By.id(<<submit button>>).click(); // url -> /postRegister

System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl()); //
```

result: url /register

Expected: url /postRegister

Comment: Did you put some wait after, this statement and tried getCurrentURL()? driver.findElement(By.id(<<submit button>>).click(); // url -> /postRegister

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be happening but anyhow you can use JavascriptExecutor to fetch the current url as:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return window.location.href").toString();
```

Comment: The code you provided returns the following:
FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (a972635d-etc...) and it returns different value on each run... did i use something wrong maybe?

Comment: It shouldn't, can you please put second line in sysout and let me know the o/p.

Comment: I am just an idiot, you solved the case. When i tried it for the first time i printed the "js" part only, not the entire row. It is working like a charm. Thank you very much, post marked as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you put some wait after click, and tried getCurrentURL()? driver.findElement(By.id(<>).click(); // url -> /postRegister. 
Thread.Sleep(10000); //put some suitable wait or atleast it tries to navigate to post register page.
System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

Comment: Yes, I have waited for 30 seconds, even tried the not recommended Thread.sleep(30000), and the url was still incorrect (the ui changed, but the returned url was the incorrect one)